# matching observation dates per user ID and giving a matching score R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a Data frame "ds" with data as shown below
I'm trying to calculate matches in column "date" for user by user

```
user_id  observation       date
1           efd         2005-01-11
1           vev4        2005-01-10
1           23e         2005-01-10
1           rvw         2005-01-11
2           3dfv        2005-01-08
2           cfv         2005-01-08
2           dfv         2005-01-11
2           rvw         2005-02-11
2           rvw         2005-02-17
2           rvw         2005-02-21
3           rvw         2005-02-24
3           rvw         2005-03-09
3           efd         2005-03-25
4           23e         2005-03-12
4           23e         2005-03-12
5           23e         2005-03-15
6           efd         2005-03-16
6           23e         2005-03-16
6           23e         2005-03-18
7           3dfv        2005-03-24
7           rvw         2005-03-24
7           3dfv        2005-03-22
7           3dfv        2005-03-23
```

so desired result would be some like :

```
user_id observation         date    Match_num
1           efd         2005-01-11      2
1           vev4        2005-01-10  
1           23e         2005-01-10  
1           rvw         2005-01-11  
2           3dfv        2005-01-08      2
2           cfv         2005-01-08  
2           dfv         2005-01-11  
2           rvw         2005-02-11  
2           rvw         2005-02-17  
2           rvw         2005-02-21  
3           rvw         2005-02-24      0
3           rvw         2005-03-09  
3           efd         2005-03-25  
4           23e         2005-03-12      1
4           23e         2005-03-12  
5           23e         2005-03-15      0
6           efd         2005-03-16      1
6           23e         2005-03-16  
6           23e         2005-03-18  
7           3dfv        2005-03-24      1
7           rvw         2005-03-24  
7           3dfv        2005-03-22  
7           3dfv        2005-03-23
```

I know  how to do with "ave" calculating percentage:

ds$match_num <- with(ds, ave(date, customer_id, FUN=function(x) c(sum(x)/length(x), rep(NA,length(x)-1))))

but it is not working for matching dates and I need to calculate exact numbers of matches not percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP wants the number of duplicates

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ds)[, Match_num:= uniqueN(date[duplicated(date)]) , .(user_id)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it seems it is working but , is there any way to modify the output to have only one record per user Id ?

Comment: @BeginwithR Do you want to subet the dataset with the first observation/last observation etc.?  It is not clear from the description.

Comment: Hi, I was looking to get a total of duplicates,  one record per user_id,

Comment: @BeginwithR In that case just place it in a `list` ie. `setDT(ds)[, list(Match_num = uniqueN(date[duplicated(date)])) , .(user_id)]`

Answer (score 2):

You could try with `data.table` (the following will fill out the Match_num column completely instead of adding just a few values)

```
library(data.table)
DS <- data.table(ds)
DS[, Match_num := .N, by=list(user_id, date)]
```